# Is garbage collection used for reclaiming just heap objects or objects in both heap and stack?

Tags: java, c#, python, garbage-collection, programming-languages

I am reading Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott, and wonder about the following question:

Is garbage collection (e.g. by reference count) used for reclaiming just heap objects or objects in both heap and stack?

For example, in Python, Java and C#, which use garbage collection, 
are stack objects deallocated automatically without garbage collection once they are out of scope?

Comment: @DiskJunky do you mean deallocation of stack objects are controlled by garbage collector?

Comment: In C# objects are managed in a much more complex way than just "stack" and "heap". There are different levels of memory assignment (Gen0 to Gen2), the Large Object Heap, etc. In context of your question C# GC does both

Comment: they're never truly on the stack in the traditional sense to begin with. How memory is assigned and deallocated is quite complex in C#. Excluding unmanaged references, the GC will traverse all relevant parts of memory to deallocate as necessary

Comment: This is really too broad of a question. You need to narrow it down. C#, Python, and Java all have very different ways of garbage collecting. If you want to know about Python garbage collector, asking only about Python. Same goes for C#, and Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is garbage collection (e.g. by reference count) used for reclaiming just heap objects or objects in both heap and stack?

It's used just for heap objects. Stack is used exactly for objects with guaranteed short lifetimes (i.e. they do not live past the function which created them). For those objects, garbage collection is unnecessary.

Though figuring out which objects are "heap objects" may not be trivial. For example, the JVM uses escape analysis to detect objects which can be allocated on the stack instead of the heap. Another example is C#, where a value type local variable in an `async` method is usually going to be allocated on the heap.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you, Java has both heap and stack objects (as in your example), and garbage collection only applies to heap objects and not to stack objects. Does C# also have stack objects? Could you give some example? Does Python also have both stack and heap objects? (If implementation matters, CPython)

Comment: Some implementations of JVM are using garbage collection for reclaiming unused stack frames. If JVM is not using native stack, using on heap list of frame objects is viable strategy.

Comment: @Tim In both Java and C#, local variables of primitive types, like `int`, are usually allocated on the stack. C# also has custom value types, like `DateTime`, which behaves the same.

Comment: @svick  by "primitive types", do you mean predefined types, i.e. types as opposed to custom types?

Answer (score 1):

There is no any "deallocation" in stack at all. So, yes, garbage collector is not involved in this process. Everything that you put into stack is being forgot by program once you don't need it. App usually simply subtracts size of object in bytes from stack's pointer, which is equivalent to cleaning everything placed last time.

Comment: Thanks. Do Python, Java and C# have stack objects?

Comment: In C# value objects is stored in stack. Java works similar if as I remember. Memory managment in Python depends on it's implementations.

Comment: @DanilEroshenko "In C# value objects is stored in stack." That's a dangerously wrong simplification.

Comment: Yep, I heard about boxing.But it will be a lot of text if I won't simplify. The question is "Is garbage collection is involved" and short answer is "No" anyway.

Comment: @DanilEroshenko It's not just boxing. For example, with `class C { int i; }`, `i` will be allocated on the heap (at least with the current CLR implementation). And in those cases, GC *is* involved.

Comment: @svick Why is ""In C# value objects is stored in stack"  a dangerous simplication? Is it mostly true? When is it not true?

Comment: If you use "int x = 5;" in method, you will get it stored in stack. But it will be stored to heap if you use "object x = 5;" - although x is still five, it's not value object now, cos object is reference type. Class fields also is stored in heap (it's a part of a reference type in this case). So, value type you clearly initialize as local variable is stored in a stack. But you can box it to heap by using any operation that requires reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collector in java just claims the objects in heap but it does trace the stack memory to see if any of the heap objects are still being referenced before they can be claimed.Stack memory is claimed once the method call ends.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, Objects only reside in the heap. If this can help you.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Also, the JVM uses escape analyis to sometimes allocate objects on the stack.

Comment: Event with escape analysis, objects are not allocated on stack in HotSpot JVM. Escape analysis is enabling scalar replacement - replacing object by bunch of local variables (which are on stack obviously).